# Буфер строк в Си

Tags: c, строки

Подскажите, как создать пустой буфер, в который нити могут записывать строки? Как инициализировать этот буфер? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Какие нити?

Comment: ну потоки, которые будут писать в этот буфер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

malloc()/calloc(). Ничего инициализировать не нужно. Просто пишешь в массив.

Comment: Спасибо, то есть примерно следующее char *s[] = malloc(256), так?

Comment: Примерно. `char *s = malloc(256);`. А вот насчёт "просто пишешь" -- там уже смешнее. Синхронизировать надо, однако.

Comment: с синхронизацией более-менее, там ждущие блокировки, присоединения будут. Спасибо всем, кто присоединился к ответу, не ожидал такой оперативности!

Comment: За правильные ответы награждаем.

Comment: честно говоря не знаю, как награждать. У меня вроде бы недостаточно очков уважения)

Comment: @mikillskegg лёгкий рэкет?

Comment: @alexlz, борьба за справедливость

Answer (score 1):

Странно ты как-то изучаешь язык. Про потоки знаешь, а про выделение памяти - нет. Кстати, используя malloc и calloc, не забывай освобождать память вызовом free.

Если заранее известно, какого размера нужен буфер, можно использовать обычный массив с передачей указателя другому потоку. Обычный массив расположен на стеке, и выделяется очень быстро. И освобождать его не надо будет. Если заранее не известно, то можно всё равно выделить память на стеке при помощи alloca. Её тоже не надо освобождать.

Comment: Хороший совет. Только при выделении в стеке надо следить, чтобы этот фрейм стека не освободился раньше времени. А то можно написать выделения массива в стеке в теле функции и возврат этого адреса выше. Вот смеху-то будет. Уж лучше стек не трогать. Или куча, или static

Answer (score 0):

Буфер? Может человек имеет ввиду обычный объект типа string. Если это так, то в этом ничего сложного нет:

```
...
#include<string>
...
string str;  // инициализация пустого объекта String, буфера строки
...
```

Comment: Вы вопрос читали? Метки - Си. Какой string?

Comment: А в С имеется string?

Comment: Начнем с того, что в Си нет объектов.